# How to bypass IncrediBuild console if not installed?

Tags: linux, bash, continuous-integration, incredibuild

There are some bash scripts running on our build machines where IncrediBuild is installed. The idea of IncrediBuild is to utilize all cores available in the network to speed up the build process.

Example shell script:

```
...
ib_console cmake --build .
```

The shell script shall not be changed. I would like to run the script on machines without ib_console. Is there a possibility to somehow simulate it or forward the call to cmake ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@alex: the alias works from the shell but not in the shell script above since aliases are not expanded in non interactive shell scripts.

With [Why doesn't my Bash script recognize aliases?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1496/why-doesnt-my-bash-script-recognize-aliases?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) I could fix it.

```
if ! [ -f 'whereis ib_console' ]; then
    ib_console()
    {
        echo "ib_console dummy: run '$@'..."
        $@
        echo "ib_console dummy: done"
    }
    export -f ib_console
fi
```

It is recommended to run 'exec bash' after updating .bashrc

Comment: Seems like a nice and clean solution. Top.

Answer (score 3):

Place this into your `.bashrc` file:

```
if [ ! -f ´whereis ib_console´ ] then
    alias ib_console='$@'
fi
```

Explanation:

- **-f**  checks, whether the ib_console binary exists
- **$@** take all arguments into one single string (they are then executed standalone)